# Emacs autocomplete inside Python string?

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

I'm new to emacs and am trying to figure out how to make auto-complete mode auto complete while my cursor is inside quotes.

For example, while writing Python (I'm using emacs-jedi) I'd love to be able to autocomplete dictionary lookups.  It doesn't even need to introspect my dictionary, just offer the word if it has already been used in the buffer.

```
data = {"test_auto_complete": 1}
data['test_
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AC does not complete when you are in face specified by `ac-disable-faces`.  It is `'(font-lock-comment-face font-lock-string-face font-lock-doc-face)` by default.  Remove `font-lock-string-face` from it or simply remove all:

```
(setq ac-disable-faces nil)
```

Answer (score 5):

For string literals, use either `dabbrev-expand` or `hippie-expand`.

I keep them bound to `M-/` and `S-/` (ie. `Meta /` and `Super /`) YMMV

This won't go through the `auto-complete` interface, if you really want that, there will be a way, but is that really necessary?

Note: `hippie-expand` will expand/autocomplete from the filesystem, and other places (including everything `dabbrev-expand` does.)

`dabbrev-expand` will only expand from the open buffers and the abbrev dictionary.

#### Edit: using autocomplete with dabbrev

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ac-dabbrev.el - this emacs lisp will make `dabbrev` a source for auto-complete